# What will be the output of the following program written in C?

Tags: c

I am a novice for C language.but I could understand why this 
following code is giving **output as 'A'**.

one thing that is bothering me is the array name p in the 
printf statement.how this p is being treated by the compiler?

**How can the p is replaced by the character array "%c\n" after line no 5**?

I know that this is a silly question so sorry to post this hare.

Can anyone will help me to understand the concept behind this?

```
 line1:      #include<stdio.h>
 line2:      int main()
 line3:      {
 line4:          char p[]="%d\n";
 line5:          p[1]='c';
 line6:          printf(p,65);
 line7:          return 0;
             }
```

Comment: What is in `p` before line 5? What about after line 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument to `printf()` is a `const char*` that contains the format specifiers. It is more common to see it as a string literal:

```
printf("%c\n", 65);
```

but it is legal to use a variable containing a string.

The assignment of `p[1] = 'c'` changes the `d` to `c` in the buffer `p`, resulting in the character `A` (as `65` is decimal value for `A`) being written to standard output (as `%c` instructs `printf()` to print the character, rather than `%d` which will print the numeric value).

Comment: thanks a lot sir. how can I strengthen my C skills? is there any link you have that can help me to understand the C in a deep way

Comment: @krishnaChandra, no problem. The best way would to get a recommended book. This would be a good starting place: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language .

Answer (score 2):

You are not replacing the whole array, just the character at array's offset #1 (second character). you are replacing it with 'c' making the content to be "%c\n" which, when used as a formatting string, formats the integer 65 as an upper-case Latin A

Comment: but is it valid c statement to use an arry name instead of using the format string in printf() function

Comment: of course it is, it's a parameter to a function, you are free to provide an explicit string "like this one" or a pointer to a memory where such a string is located, like `p`. Just remember that if you are using an array of characters then it **must** be terminated with a `'\0'` marker at the end of it

Answer (score 1):

In line 6: 
`printf(p,65);` 
will be changed to 
 `printf("%c\n",65);`  Ascii Value of 'A' is 65. 
http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

Explanation below:

```
char p[]="%d\n";
```

After the above executes, P will contain -> "%d\n"

```
 line5:          p[1]='c';
```

Here, P will now be "%c\n", as you are changing the 1th character of a zero based indexing.

```
line6:          printf(p,65);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
printf("%c\n",65)
```

or

```
printf("%c\n",'A')
```

Hence you get the output of **A**

Answer (score 0):

```
     #include<stdio.h>
       int main()
       {
          char p[]="%d\n";   #This is stored at p[1]
          p[1]='c'           # d is replaced by c
          printf(p,65);      # p is taken as p[1] and is replaced by "%c\n"
           return 0;
         }
```

output:
              A   # ASCII value 65

If you give the value as 66 output will be 'B" and so on.